# SwiftUI Search bar crashes when trying to filter results

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a textfield that, when active, shows the filtered results from an array of "City" structs. When I type certain letters it behaves as expected, but typing other letters (consistent) crashes the app with "Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI". The city struct has an id and has the Identifiable and Hashable protocols. Here is a snippet of the code that might help troubleshoot:

```
struct City: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
  let id: String
  let city: String
  let state: String
}

@State var cities : [City] = Bundle.main.decode("cities.json")
    
...

TextField(placeholder, text: $searchText) { (isEditing) in
   showingDropdown = isEditing
}

...

if showingDropdown && !searchText.isEmpty {
      
      ScrollView {
        LazyVStack {
          ForEach(cities.filter { $0.city.contains(searchText)}) { city in
            HStack {
              Text(city.city)
              Text("(\(city.id))")
                .foregroundColor(.lightGrayWeFly)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
              input = city.id
              searchText = city.city
              showingDropdown.toggle()
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

It's possible that I made an error when I created the JSON file but I'm having trouble narrowing things down.

Comment: First guess: Are you sure all `id`s in your cities.json are unique?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I created the data and might have missed something, so I'll check that first!

Comment: I think that fixed it, thanks for the help! I should have re-checked my data first...